# HTML5 Video not playing, NAN duration

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am working to play a collection of videos consecutively. My strategy to do this was to have an array containing each filename, create a videotag which has the {filename} parameter defined within a do while loop, the do while replaces the videotag with the array element. The issue i am having is that the video will not play when the clip.play() function is called? My second issue is that in order to determine whether or not to move to the next video i compare clip.currentTime to clip.duration but for some season i am getting NAN for clip.duration?

**HTML FILE**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- modernize older browsers -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

        <title>Starter File</title>

        <!-- enable responsive web design -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />

        <!-- stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link media="only screen and (max-width: 980px)" href="css/tablet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link media="only screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="css/mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/videoPlayerQeued.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="top-banner">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <img src="images/fantasytv-logo.png"/>
                <div>your team, on your time</div>
            </div>

            <div class="provider-container-interface">
                <img src="images/yahoo-signed-in.png"/>
            </div>

        </div><!--end of top banner -->

        <div class="interface-container">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>MY LEAGUES</li>
                <li>SETTINGS</li>
                <li>SIGN OUT</li>
            </ul><!--end menu-->
            <div class="fix"></div>

            <div class="date-shift-banner">
                <div class="left-arrow">
                    <img src="images/left-arrow.png"/>
                </div>

                <div class="date">
                    June 23, 2013
                </div>

                <div class="right-arrow">
                    <img src="images/right-arrow.png"/>
                </div>
            </div><!--end date banner-->

            <div class="stats-profile-container">
                <div class="stats-container">
                    <div class="stats-title-container">
                        <div><div class="padding-stat-title-offense">OFFENSE</div></div>
                        <div><div class="padding-stat-title-pitching">PITCHING</div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fix"></div>

                    <table class="offense">

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>R</td>
                            <td>AVG</td>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>HR</td>
                            <td>SB</td>
                            <td>RBI</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>.000</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--end stats table-->

                    <table class="pitching">
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>W</td>
                            <td>L</td>
                            <td>H</td>
                            <td>K</td>
                            <td>WHIP</td>
                            <td>ERA</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>.000</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table><!--end stats table-->

                </div><!--end stats container-->

                <div class="player-profile-container">
                    <img class="player-picture" src=""/>

                    <div class="player-name-team-container">
                        <div class="player-name"></div>
                        <div class="player-team"></div>
                    </div><!-- end player name team container -->
                </div><!--end player profile container-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div><!--end stats and profile container-->

            <div class="video-roster-container">
                <div class="video-container">
                    <div class="video-container-padding">
                        <div class="fantasy-team">TEAM: <span>YANKEEFAN</span></div>
                        <div class="video-player">
                            <video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls autobuffer>
                                    <source src="cuddyer.mov" type="video/mp4">
                                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                            </video>    <!--end video container -->

                        </div><!--end video player-->
                    </div><!--end video container padding-->
                </div><!--end video container-->

                <div class="roster-container">
                <div class="play-all-container">
                <div class="play-all"><img src="images/play-all-arrow.png"/></div><div class="watch-all-players">Watch All Players</div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                </div>

                    <ul class="player-video-buttons">
                        <li id="test"><span>C</span><span>Willin Rosario</span><span class="team">Colorado Rockies</span></li>
                        <li><span>1B</span><span>Chris Davis</span><span class="team">Baltimore Orioles</span></li>
                        <li><span>2B</span><span>Ian Kinsler</span><span class="team">Detroit Tigers</span></li>
                        <li><span>SS</span><span>Derek Jeter</span><span class="team">New York Yankees</span></li>
                        <li><span>3B</span><span>Evan Longoria</span><span class="team">Tampa Bay Rays</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Mike Trout</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Angels</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Josh Hamilton</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Angels</span></li>
                        <li><span>OF</span><span>Michael Cuddyer</span><span class="team">Colorado Rockies</span></li>
                        <li><span>U</span><span>David Ortiz</span><span class="team">Boston Red Sox</span></li>
                        <li><span>P</span><span>Clayton Kershaw</span><span class="team">Los Angeles Dodgers</span></li>
                        <li><span>P</span><span>Matt Harvey</span><span class="team">New York Mets</span></li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--end roster container-->
                <div class="fix"></div>
            </div><!-- end video roster container-->
        </div><!--end interface container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript File**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.play-all').on("click", function(){
            var videoFileArray;
            var pictureFileArray;
            var rosterArray = LoadRosterFromButtons();
            rosterArray = FormatArray(rosterArray);
            videoFileArray = AddMovieExtensions(rosterArray);
            // PlayAllVideos(videoFileArray);
            var x = PlayAllVideos(videoFileArray);
            // AlertRosterArray(videoFileArray);
        });
    })

    // function PlayFirstVideo(fileArray){
        // videoTag = '<video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls autoplay><source src="{fileName}" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
        // videoTag = videoTag.replace('{fileName}', fileArray[0]);
        // $('.video-player').empty();
        // $('.video-player').html(videoTag);
        // return videoTag;
    // }

    function PlayAllVideos(fileArray){
        var videoCurrentTime;
        var videoDuration;
        var currentArrayPosition = 0;


    do{
        var videoTag = '<video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls autoplay><source src="{fileName}" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
        videoTag = videoTag.replace('{fileName}', fileArray[currentArrayPosition]);
        $('.video-player').empty();
        $('.video-player').html(videoTag);
        var clip = document.getElementById('play-video'); //current video 
        if(clip === undefined){
            alert('clip is undefined');
        }
        else{
            clip.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
                console.log(clip.duration);
            });
            clip.load();
            clip.play();
        }
        videoDuration = clip.duration;
        videoDuration = videoDuration.toFixed(1);

        do{
            videoCurrentTime = videoTimeCounterUpdate(clip);
        }while(videoCurrentTime < videoDuration);


        if(videoCurrentTime === videoDuration){
            currentArrayPosition += 1
            alert('end of video');
            continue;
        }

        currentArrayPosition += 1
    }while(currentArrayPosition < fileArray.length);

    // for(var i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++ ){
        // var videoTag = '<video  id="play-video" width="588" height="318" controls autoplay><source src="{fileName}" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>';
        // videoTag = videoTag.replace('{fileName}', fileArray[i]);
        // $('.video-player').empty();
        // $('.video-player').html(videoTag);
        // var clip = document.getElementById('play-video'); //current video 
        // clip.play()
        // // if(clip === undefined){
            // // alert('clip is undefined');
        // // }
        // // else{
            // // clip.play();
        // // }
        // videoDuration = clip.duration;
        // videoDuration = videoDuration.toFixed(1);

        // do{
            // videoCurrentTime = videoTimeCounterUpdate(clip);
        // }while(videoCurrentTime < videoDuration);


        // if(videoCurrentTime === videoDuration){
            // alert('end of video');
            // continue;
        // }
    // }
}

    function AddMovieExtensions(roster){
        var rosterArrayFormatted = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++ ){
            rosterArrayFormatted[i] = roster[i] + '.mov';
        }
        return rosterArrayFormatted;
    }


    function LoadRosterFromButtons(){
    //Loads current roster into memory from button labels
        var currentC = "Willin Rosario";
        var current1B = "1b Man";
        var current2B = "current 2b";
        var currentSS = "current SS";
        var current3B = "current TB";
        var currentOF1 = "OF1";
        var currentOF2 = "OF2";
        var currentOF3 = "OF3";
        var currentU = "This is A U";
        var currentP1 = "P1";
        var currentP2 = "P2";
        var rosterArray = [currentC, current1B, current2B, currentSS, current3B, currentOF1, currentOF2, currentOF3, currentU, currentP1, currentP2];
        return rosterArray;
    }

    function FormatArray(roster){
    //remove spaces and lowercase all letters
    var rosterArrayFormatted = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++ ){
            rosterArrayFormatted[i] = roster[i].replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
        }
    return rosterArrayFormatted;
    }

    function AlertRosterArray(roster){
        for(var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++ ){
            alert(roster[i]);
        }
    }


    // function PlayAllVideos(fileArray){
        // for(var i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++ ){
            // do{

            // }while();
        // }
    // }

    function videoTimeCounterUpdate(clipObject){
        var clipTime = clipObject.currentTime;
        clipTime = clipTime.toFixed(1);
        var runTimeUpdate = setTimeout(videoTimeCounterUpdate, 100); //Round to .x digit    
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use .readyState() to understand if all is good with the video loading?

Comment: From what im finding it looks like .readystate is a property of the html5 video tag. I have not checked it because i was not aware of it but i will do this when i get home.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're loading quicktime video files. Try using .mp4 files, and you'll need a .webm version as well to play in Firefox. Rather than set a `src` attribute on the video tag, you'll want to make two "source" tags. See the example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#Examples

Also, once you get it playing, it's easiest to detect the end of the video by listening for the 'ended' event.

Comment: I have typically been debugging in Chrome. I am pretty sure the files that i am using which are stored locally in the same folder as the html file are ".mp4" files.  I will try the "source tag" vs "source attribute" solution once i get home. Thanks for the ended event solution for once i get my video playing.

Comment: correction, i was passing .mov files i will try the .mp4 solution

Comment: You can always try to open the video file directly in your browser. If it can't play it that way, you know the problem is with the file and not your javascript.

Comment: so i have confirmed that the videos work when opening within a browser. I am also adding a source tag instead of a src attribute to the video tag.  i am not sure why the video will not play. I have checked my video tag readystate and i keep getting 0. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: Would you like to post a live link? I'll take a look.

Comment: I am currently developing this locally, i do have a site up but the code has not been updated. I will update the files tonight when i get home. The files should be updated after 8PM EST. www.fantasytvnetwork.com I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I can't see anything without logging in, and I think it would be unwise to type my yahoo credentials into a site that is not yahoo. I suggest you reconsider your authentication/security model.

Comment: Lol, i havent updated the code yet because i already figured it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think all that you need is to add `.get(0)` before any video related functions. E.g. `.get(0).play()`.

The issue is in WebKit browsers; the video metadata is loaded after the video so is not available when the JS runs. You need to query the readyState attribute; this has a series of values from 0 to 4, letting you know what state the video is in; when the metadata has loaded you'll get a value of 1.

There's more information about media element attributes on developer.mozilla.org.